# Shell32 call fails from an event handler, but works from Main

Tags: c#, com-interop

I hope the explanation makes sense.
I have a line

```
(new Shell()).NameSpace(TargetDirectory).CopyHere(SourceFile, 16 | 2048);
```

It works just fine when I'm calling it sequentially. Meaning I have my Main method and in that, I call the method that contains the line.
What doesn't work is calling the containing method from an event. I have a FileSystemWatcher and in it's Changed event, I call the method containing this line. Then I get

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of     type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Shell32.Shell'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{34936BA1-67AD-4C41-99B8-8C12DFF1E974}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'
```

And here's where I'm stuck. I now that line itself works just fine so I've no idea what to repair and how.

Comment: Is there particular reason for using the shell API for copying?

Comment: Yes. The copy operation may or may not need administrative privileges. Since it may not need administrative privileges, I don't want to simply manifest my program for always requiring them. The shell API has the big advantage of displaying a UAC prompt if administrative privileges are needed but not if not. Right now, I'm looking into restarting my program with administrative privileges if they're needed, but I thought that using the shell for that is more elegant.

Comment: So, I don't have a definite answer about it, but a few pointers, since I had this exact issue yesterday (for another COM object though).

Is the event in the same project/assembly as your main?

Have you made your assembly visible in COM?

Is your assembly registered?

Comment: It's ll in the same Program.cs file. Making the assembly visible does exactly nothing, registering does the same.

Comment: It may be a threading model issue. FSW events may arrive in any thread and I think this Shell object requires an STA thread. If fsw.SynchronizingObject is null you should set it to something like a Form or Control; Otherwise just use its BeginInvoke method instead of calling the Shell object directly.

Comment: Dumb question maybe, but how do I mark your reply as the answer?